# What are the best practices when using Flutter Firestore plugin? Should creating multiple instances be avoided?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

- When reading a document that has nested collections and documents inside these collections, if only the parent doc is targeted, will the nested docs be read as well? Will they count as reads?
- Having different Firestore instances on different widgets to listen/stream to the same doc counts as two reads? Is it recommended to create the instance in one place and then use Provider throughout the app?

The most efficient way would be something like this...

```dart
    class DataSource {
      static a.Future<FirebaseUser> getFirebaseUser() async {
        return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      }
}
```

or simply repeat

```dart
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
```

on every widget that needs this information?

That video about the 30K bill frightened me to do something basic REALLY wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When reading a document that has nested collections and documents inside these collections, if only the parent doc is targeted, will the nested docs be read as well? Will they count as reads?

Reading from Firestore is shallow. Reading a document does not read from its subcollections.

> Having different Firestore instances on different widgets to listen/stream to the same doc counts as two reads?

It depends on how you implement the reading. In general, it is recommended to keep a single listener open on the document(s) you're interested in. So you may want to consider passing the stream around.

> That video about the 30K bill frightened me to do something basic REALLY wrong.

In that case I recommend starting development by using Firebase's [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite). You can locally develop your code, check your usage on that local project, without ever getting any bill for Firestore usage (or any of the other emulates services, such as Cloud Functions).